# Save dynamically entered table data between sessions and fill table with saved data on a new session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a "task list" where a user can post a number via a text box that is displayed below the textbox in a list with checkboxes. When the user ticks the checkboxes and hits delete it should delete the checked tasks. This is working fine but I cannot figure out how to retain the data on the page between sessions. I want anyone to be able to post a task and anyone at any future point to be able to pull up the page, see the tasks already posted, and add tasks or delete ones already there. I am not sure what the best way to retain the data between sessions might be. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the HTML portion:

```
<h2 align="center"><u>Enter New Tasks Below</u></h2> 
<h3 align="center">
Type your new task into the text box below and click "Add".<br/><br/>
Once a task or multiple tasks have been completed, check the box next to the task/tasks you would like to remove and click the "Delete Selected Items" button.</h3>


<div class="unconFN" style="margin-right:475px; width:450px; border:2px;">
    <table id="tasksFN" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <h4>FieldNation UnConfirmed WO Numbers</h4>
        <input type="text" id="newFN" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="addFN" value="Add"  />
        <br /><br />
    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="delFN" value="Delete Selected Items" hidden="true" />
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript/JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

function checkFN(){
   //function to hide delete button if table is empty
   var x = document.getElementById("tasksFN").rows.length;
   if(x == 0){
       $("#delFN").hide(); 
   }else{
        $("#delFN").show();
   }
}

//function to add a new row from the data in the textbox to the table
$("#addFN").click(function() {
     var val = $("#newFN").val();
     var newTxt = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
     $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
     $("#tasksFN").append(newTxt);
     $("#newFN").val("");
     $("#delFN").show();
});

//function for delete button to remove checked rows
$("#delFN").click(function() {
     $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });
     checkFN();//checks if delete button should be hidden or not
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the value of your val when you console.log(val);?

Comment: I'm relatively new to much of this. How would I implement that?